# Docker not working Ubuntu 20.04 on windows

Tags: docker, ubuntu, hyperledger-fabric, wsl-2

I am currently trying to download Hyperledger Fabric through Ubuntu 20.04. I downloaded ubuntu through the windows store. I have also downloaded docker desktop and set up WSL 2 backend for Ubuntu. However, after installing docker.io through the ubuntu terminal using

```
sudo apt-get install docker.io
```

I was trying to enable it. As ubuntu was using Sysvinit instead of systemd i used the following to try and enable docker.

```
sudo service docker start
```

which returned

```
docker: unrecognized service
```

I am new to linux so any suggestions or anything obvious I have missed that will fix this issue would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: In my opinion it is not a question related to hyperledger fabric. How about simplifying the question a bit and removing the `hyperledger-fabric` tag?

Comment: I included to hyperledger fabric tag as I am installing the prerequisites and thought someone who has it set it up using windows, as I am trying to do, may have come across the same issue and know how to fix it. However, i can remove the tag if the post is not unrelated. Will also edit the wording in the question.

Comment: I think it might be desirable for you to add that tag for exposure. But if this is a tool/language different from the real problem, i.e. if it could be confusing it would be right to be edited, and I agree with it. [meta.stackoverflow.tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288213/is-requesting-removal-of-a-single-incorrect-tag-big-enough-to-make-an-edit)
Of course, I think it's on the borderline with the benefits of exposure you were talking about. That's why I didn't do the edit, and I asked for your thoughts first.

Answer (score 3):

The ubuntu distribution that runs in WSL differs from normal ubuntu in key ways. One of them is that it doesn't have the standard linux initialization system.

1. service: starts services defined in the SysV init system.  If you do ls /etc/init.d/ you will see services.  When I look in my WSL installation, I see cron. So this works (but probably doesn't survive a reboot):

   sudo service cron start

   There is no init script for docker, so that won't work.
2. systemctl (systemd): starts services defined in the systemd system. This is probably what you want, except, if you run:

   sudo systemctl start docker

you get:

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
```

So, you'll need to start docker manually, not using the normal initialization systems.

This leads us to the real answer:

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/

According to the docker docs, you don't run docker as a service on linux.  Install docker on windows and let it interact with the docker engine on WSL to run your containers.

Comment: Note that "Docker for Windows" is a paid product for commercial enterprises. Then again, commercial enterprises will have no problem paying.

Answer (score 0):

For me a simple restart of Windows solved this issue:

I'm using Ubuntu in WSL2 and I'm trying to start a container inside the WSL2, and it gives me this error:
Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 0.0.0.0:8443 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:8443: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.